# Are DXF polyface mandatory?

Tags: dxf

I'm dealing with DXF files in Python. Reading only.

So far every file I've opened has Polyfaces defined (besides of Lines, arcs and circles...). I'm planning to do all my calculations using polyfaces only. But I'm afraid that some other 3D software saves a DXF without a polyface in it. Since I couldn't find any information that tells me they are mandatory I want to know how to be safe that my code will not fail by lack of polyfaces.

Should I trust more in Lines and Arcs instead? Are they mandatory?

Comment: I have not dealt specifically with your situation but if you look here:

http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acad2000/dxf/entities_section.htm

You will see that there is also 3DFACE entities too, along with several other types. I suppose it depends where your DXF data has come from in the first place. That would govern the types of elements they support.

Sorry if I miss-understood your issue.

Comment: No @AndrewTruckle you got it right. And at the end I've used other softwares that generated different DXF extructures (so you supposed right), and I give up with my approach. I finalized my project using a python port of the great http://www.assimp.org/ library.